# Why does my second loaded subapp stop after FlexEvent.INITIALIZE

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

I have a Flex 4 application that loads Flex 4 applications into it by using the mx.controls.SWFLoader component. I load the same swf-subapp several times as each subapp also runs standalone, and the content of the subapp is determined by a XML that I pass into it via the loader context.

This has worked until recently, but now, the second time I load the same swf (with a different xml) the loaded swf stops executing anything after the FlexEvent.INITIALIZE is triggered (I'm not doing anything in my initialized event handler). In other words, I don't get a CreationComplete event, which is where I start my code (and worse, no errors either).

As I've been working on a different part of my main application, I can't quite remember which change crashed my project, but what I do remember is that I updated my Flex SDK and I've hade similar silent errors in relation to a SDK upgrade earlier.

In my main application I do cleanup after myself before loading a new swf, so it shouldn't be garbage laying around.

Please help!

Comment: Have you recently changed the version of the Flash player you are using?

Comment: Nope. It's the same as when I started the project.

Comment: could you please post some code reproducing this behaviour (also writing it if you decide to post a sample or copying it out of a big project might help itself)? and what are your sdk and player versions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

There was an enterframe handler that kept the first instance of the swf in memory, that in some way blocked the next one from loading (eventhough I used the removeAllElements on the parent container and hoped that would do the trick).

Now I use a NativeSignal and remove all listeners from that on onRemove handler (RobotLegs). Works like a charm.